# Get the environment name in a Twig template with Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

Is there a way to get the name of the current environment in a Twig template? I'd like to set some CSS style values depending on it.

Answer (score 183, accepted):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/app_variable.html:

```
<p>Application Environment: {{ app.environment }}</p>
```

Comment: It slipped my eye, sorry about that... Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: It would have been helpful to provide the actual answer with the link.

Answer (score 46):

Use

```
app.environment
```

e.g.

```
{% extends app.environment == 'dev' ? "::dev_layout.html.twig" : "::layout.html.twig" %}
```

Answer (score 25):

Or you can use

```
app.debug
```

This returns true if debug is enabled. 
This is usually the case in the dev environment, however debug can be enabled in any of the environments... prod, test, dev, etc....

Comment: app.debug returns true only when debugging is enabled. Although enabling debug mode in the production environment is generally a bad idea, it's not impossible it is turned on.

Comment: Debug can be enabled or disabled for any environment. Also, there are more than just two environments possible (I usually use 3 or 4), so a boolean is of little help.

Comment: Do not use this, use app. environment

Comment: Do not use is not helpful. Explain why.

Comment: Although this is not the proper answer to the OP, this is more useful